# How does writing heading (h1, h2, h3) tags helps with SEO?

Tags: html, seo, semantic-markup

I read somewhere that using h1 h2 h3 properly on the page helps with Search Engine Optimization. How is that? Can somebody tell me the proper use of these or other tags or point me to some resource where i can get an understanding of it.

Comment: I guess it's just a logical thing. If I read HTML with my human eyes I can clearly see where there are headings which represent a block of content. Why should a search spider thingy be any different? I have a feeling that the more logical the markup for your content is, the better your content will be indexed. I wouldn't index content if it was too hard to tell what each segment of content is meant to be. `<span>`s tell me nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well there are dozens of factors which help you optimize your website or web-pages. Heading tags (h1, h2...) are just one of them, so if you truly want to optimize your web-pages, please make sure that web-page must comply with the below best & valuable ranking factors.

1. Unique Title relevant to the content of web-page
2. Snippets description which describe whole details in short of
   webpage
3. Unique & proper formatted content
4. Heading tag (H1) with the most relevant keyword to the webpage, try
   to place in upper portion of the page
5. Bold content which is more relevant & valuable within content
6. Well optimize Images Footer links
7. Recommend related content

Answer (score 5):

These indicate not only the size of the heading but also the **importance**.

The main headline will need an "**h1**" code to give it the greatest importance.

The main sub-headings, which are numbers one, two, and so on in the article outline deserve an "**h2**" showing they are next in line when it comes to importance.

The "**h3**" can be given to sub-headings under the main sub-headings such as "a,b,c" points in the article outline above.

**SEO and Heading Tags**

When the importance of a heading is established with HTML tags, you're actually making it easy for the search engine robots to determine what your web page is all about.  The search engine doesn't have to guess at it.  It can see exactly what your main topic is and place you under the appropriate keywords so your potential customers will be able to find you on the WWW.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, SEO is a fairly unknowable subject - it's a continuous arms race between the search engines and the spam kings. There's a lot of folklore, a lot of hearsay, and a things change all the time.

Having said that, Google do give general advice - http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=35769&hl=en.

By writing standards-compliant, semantic HTML, you make it easier for the search engine to interpret your content. This, in turn, allows it to decide if your content is relevant to a given search query. By saying "this is a heading" (i.e. using the h1 tag), you give Google a hint about the words in that tag - in this case, that it's probably the subject of the content.

The best resource on standards-compliant HMTL is the might Zeldman book - http://www.zeldman.com/dwws/.

Answer (score 1):

SEO is mainly focussed on keywords in the document. The main priority is the title of the page. Then it is going to the heading tags (h1,h2,h3). Then the rest of the content (Google said they are not using meta tags, but it is better to have it also).

Answer (score -1):

Using H1, H2, H3 etc in Webpage is giving preferences to the contents. Contents in H1 tags is more important than H2 tags like we do while preparing our documentation.

Also you can visit 
http://www.debojyotipal.com/h1-h2-h3-tags-for-seo/

http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/5OROBdtsmPs

which will provide more insights.